# CoreData is cleared every time the Framework gets initialised

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Am created a custom `Framework` in `Swift 3`. And I used `CoreData` in that Framework. Am create `NSObject` class for `CoreData` functionality. I init the `Framework` while launching the Application, When I `init` the framework I made a data sync from server.

Everytime the app launching the `Framework` get initialised.

Everything working fine, The Problem is when I Lauched the app the preciously synced data's are not present in the framework dataModel.

Am not clearing data base at any point. And also I check the data count of `CoreData` table before syncing the data from server, Its return 0.

Any help or Idea should be Appreciate.

Comment: Please post the code you use to init your CoreData Stack, to create/persist the object(s) and how you call it from outside the framework. Also: Are you testing on Simulator or Device?

Answer (score 0):

To save it's not enough just *not to clear* - you should explicitly call `context.save()`.